# call a function after all fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect when all my `fadeOut` are finished

My `fadeOut` are on random duration, on all item of an container.
after each fadeOut I remove item, to put a new one after all item `fadeOut`. This new Item are hiden, waiting to `fadeIn`

```
function fadeOutItem(){ 
$('div.wrapper').children('.item-box').each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1300) + 200, function(){
        $(this)[0].remove();
    });
});
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFIddle or at least some context please
But from what you have written I would say use a variable `n` and set it to be the number of divs you are fading out.  In the success function subtract 1 from this number each time and when it = 0 they have all faded out.

Comment: Side note: `$(this)[0].remove();` is semantically the same as `this.remove()`, and as pointed out in one of the answers, it won't work as `remove()` is a jQuery function, which you're trying to execute on a DOM object (after wrapping, and un-wrapping it into/from a jQuery object).

Comment: use $(this).remove();

Comment: @Jeremy, do you mean you want to wait for your all elements to finish fading out before fading the new ones in, or are fading in and out several elements concurrently?

Comment: I mean that I want wait for all elements to finish fading out before fading the new ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to know when your wrapper doesn't contain any children anymore. You could do that in the callback function of the `fadeOut` itself:

```
function fadeOutItem(){ 
    $('div.wrapper').children('.item-box').each(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1300) + 200, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            if ($('div.wrapper').children('.item-box').length === 0) {
                // add new item
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a if conditional statement to look for total elements like below

```
function fadeOutItem(){ 
$('div.wrapper').children('.item-box').each(function(i){
    $(this).fadeOut(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1300) + 200, function(){
        $(this)[0].remove();        
    });
    // Check for the instance and then add it
    if (i === $('div.wrapper').children('.item-box').length) {
                //At the last element add your elements
        }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use $(this).remove(); instead of $(this)[0].remove(); and Follow The [Link](http://api.jquery.com/click/) For More Details